# js to communicate with dom in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to listen to a click event of a link using javascript inside a wordpress project. But I could notice, NodeList is getting empty. Seem to be it's having an issue when communicating with the DOM. My attempt is as below. I created a folder called `theme` and inside the `index.php` there, below lines were added.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-next width-50 ml-auto">Next1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-next width-50 ml-auto">Next2</a>
```

Then inside the `functions.php` file imported the external scripting file as below.

```
<?php
 function pet_data1(){
  wp_enqueue_script('pet_adoption_style1', 
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/script.js', array(), false, false);
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pet_data1');
?>
```

Next the `header.php` file takes as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
</html>
```

Finally, `script.js` file which is not given the expected output is as in below.

```
const nextBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-next");
console.log("nextBtns",nextBtns)
```

When I print the `nodeList`, length is zero. But there should be 2 nodes which contains the `btn-next` class. So I think there should be an issue with wordpress structure which I have followed. Since I am new to wordpress, I need your support to fix this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with "Wordpress structure", but because you're loading the script in `<head>`, but attempting to access elements in the document body before waiting for the DOM to be ready.

`<script>` tags in the `<head>` will be downloaded and executed, before the browser parses the rest of the HTML found after `<head>` This causes issues with your selectors since when the script is executed, those elements that would have matched your selectors do not exist in the DOM tree at runtime:

[image: Script loading]

*Source: https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html*

There are two solutions:

1. Ensure that `script.js` is loaded in the footer, which means the DOM has been parsed and is ready, or
2. Wrap all DOM querying logic in `script.js` in a callback that is invoked upon the firing of `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const nextBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-next");
  console.log("nextBtns",nextBtns)
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I tried the second way.